# django taggit prevent overlapping tags across different models

Tags: python, django-models, django-taggit

I have two different models.

```
class MessageArchive(models.Model):
    from_user = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=300)
    archived_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    label = models.ForeignKey(MessageLabel, null=True, blank=True)
    archived_by = models.ForeignKey(OrgStaff)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Now say, I have defined `spam`, `todo`, `urgent` tags for messages.

and then I have another model:

```
class PersonArchive(models.Model):
        from_user = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=300)
        archived_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        label = models.ForeignKey(MessageLabel, null=True, blank=True)
        archived_by = models.ForeignKey(OrgStaff)
        tags = TaggableManager()
```

I define `awesome`, `legend`, `rockstar` for the model person. There might few more be defined.

As is quite clear, I do *not* want the tags for person and message to overlap.
How should I achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) feature on ForeignKeyFields and ManyToManyFields. Your models.py file might look like this:

```
class PersonArchive(models.Model):
    tags_field = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="people_archives", limit_choices_to={'message_archives__isnull': True})

class MessageArchive(models.Model):
    tags_field = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="message_archives", limit_choices_to={'people_archives__isnull': True})
```

Comment: what is the difference between using `tags_field` vs `TaggableManager`?? I mean, how both of them, will go along together?

Answer (score 0):

You your case, as far as I understand, you want different base families of tag for the two different models.
Take in account I'm not an expert on taggit, so the solution I'm proposing can be a bit overcomplitated, but is the first that jump me in mind by looking at the source code.
You can achieve that by extending the TaggableRel class used by TaggableManager and add a condition to the limit_choices_to parameter:

Extend TaggableRel

```
class CustomTaggableRel(TaggableRel):
    def __init__(self, field, model_name):
        super(TaggableRel, self ).__init__(field)
        self.limit_choices_to = {'content_type': model_name}
```

Than you extend TaggableManager in the following way:

```
class CustomTaggableManager(TaggableManager):
    def __init__(self, model_name=None, verbose_name=_("Tags"),
        help_text=_("A comma-separated list of tags."), through=None, blank=False):
        super(TaggableManager, self ).__init__(verbose_name, help_text, through, blank)
        self.rel = CustomTaggableRel(self, model_name)
```

Than you your models:

```
class PersonArchive(models.Model):
        .
        .
        .
        tags = CustomTaggableManager(model_name="PersonArchive")
```

This should do the trick, didn't try the solution and I write it down very fast, but this could drive you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Just dealt with this myself. I decided to let my tags intermingle because I found a way to only filter tags for specific models. This will only filter tags for `modelname`. You can expand the filter as desired.

```
Tag.objects.filter(taggit_taggeditem_items__content_type__model='modelname')
```